# Multiply columns based on position Power query

Tags: powerquery

Hello I need to multiply two columns in a new column in Power Query where the columns can change name but not position. So for example I want to multiply the second column in a table with the fourth column in the same table independently and want to be able to change name on the table headers and the code should still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table.ColumnNames(Source){1} would be the name of the 2nd column

Table.ColumnNames(Source){3} would be the name of the 4th column

You can then wrap it with Record.Field (_,x) to get the value

so the value in the second column would be

```
Record.Field (_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){1})
```

So the code below would create a new column named Mult that multiplies columns 2 and 4 without knowing their column names

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Mult", each 
     Record.Field (_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}) *
     Record.Field (_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}) )
in  #"Added Custom"
```