# Reference to a column in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, transpose

I need to transpose my data into a format that I can use in SQL and Power BI. Where my first 10 columns are all fixed and repeated for each next columns, and I have 24 for sequential months that change each month. So If It is April/21 it will start in April/21, then it goes.
Using Power Query, it is a easy task, but I would like to automatize it so I recorded a macro but it won't work, bacause in the next month the columns headers are different, and I would like to discover a way to refers to each column without using the headers.

```
Sub Transform_Base()
'
' Transform_Base_ Macro
'
  
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A:$AH"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Tabela1"
    Columns("A:AH").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Tabela1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Fonte = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Tabela1""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Tipo Alterado"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Fonte,{{""Update_Month"", type date}, {""BU"", type text}, {""Código Antigo"", type text}, {""Código Antigo2"", type text}, {""Código Antigo3"", type text}, {""Código Saubern"", type text}, {""Descrição produto"", type text}, {"" Grupo"", type " & _
        "text}, {""Tipo"", type text}, {""SAP"", type text}, {""abr/21"", Int64.Type}, {""mai/21"", Int64.Type}, {""jun/21"", Int64.Type}, {""jul/21"", Int64.Type}, {""ago/21"", Int64.Type}, {""set/21"", Int64.Type}, {""out/21"", Int64.Type}, {""nov/21"", Int64.Type}, {""dez/21"", Int64.Type}, {""jan/22"", Int64.Type}, {""fev/22"", Int64.Type}, {""mar/22"", Int64.Type}, {""a" & _
        "br/22"", Int64.Type}, {""mai/22"", Int64.Type}, {""jun/22"", Int64.Type}, {""jul/22"", Int64.Type}, {""ago/22"", Int64.Type}, {""set/22"", Int64.Type}, {""out/22"", Int64.Type}, {""nov/22"", Int64.Type}, {""dez/22"", Int64.Type}, {""jan/23"", Int64.Type}, {""fev/23"", Int64.Type}, {""mar/23"", Int64.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Colunas Não Dinâmicas"" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumn" & _
        "s(#""Tipo Alterado"", {""Update_Month"", ""BU"", ""Código Antigo"", ""Código Antigo2"", ""Código Antigo3"", ""Código Saubern"", ""Descrição produto"", "" Grupo"", ""Tipo"", ""SAP""}, ""Atributo"", ""Valor"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Colunas Renomeadas"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Colunas Não Dinâmicas"",{{""Atributo"", ""MÊS PREV""}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Colunas Renomeadas"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Tabela1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Tabela1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabela1_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: For PBI it can be better to place your dates in 1 column, did you think about it? You can repeat all constant values for each date month. Cells number probably will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, you can use this to rename all columns to Column1,Column2,Column3... dynamically, making it easier to do operations later

```
=Table.RenameColumns( Source, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ), List.Transform({1 .. List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source))}, each "Column"&Text.From(_)) } ) )
```

---

Table.ColumnNames(Source){1} would be the name of the 2nd column

Table.ColumnNames(Source){3} would be the name of the 4th column

You can then wrap it with Record.Field (_,x) to get the value

so the value in the second column would be

Record.Field (_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){1})

Comment: Hi, the idea is not to change the name of all the columns, because I need the date indication from column 11 to 34, I am looking for a way to reference by column position and turn the header into a constant, so I could create a macro for every time I handle this type of table.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903038/multiply-columns-based-on-position-power-query/66907731#66907731